# npm install -g polymer-cli is failing, saying package not available

Tags: npm, polymer, polymer-cli

I am trying to install polymer-cli, I am getting the below error. [copying from error logs]

**npm install -g polymer-cli**

My node and npm versions are as...

- node v4.4.3
- npm  v3.10.6

Can anyone please suggest how do I resolve the issue, or I have to raise any log ?
In cmd I was getting these...

```
C:\Users\kaustav.goswami>npm install -g polymer-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kaustav.goswami\\AppD
ata\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "polymer-c
li"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 no such package available : @types/clone
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/clone' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'dom5'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kaustav.goswami\npm-debug.log
```

The error logs

```
2489 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2490 error argv "D:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kaustav.goswami\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "polymer-cli"
2491 error node v4.4.3
2492 error npm  v3.10.6
2493 error code E404
2494 error 404 no such package available : @types/clone
2495 error 404
2496 error 404 '@types/clone' is not in the npm registry.
2497 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
2498 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'dom5'
2499 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
2500 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
2501 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue with npm v3.10.6. This worked for me:

```
npm up npm -g 
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Comment: Tried your approach... Still its not installing.
Node version: v6.9.4
npm version: 4.1.2